# Http POST on rest controller returns nothing Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I want to make a simple `HTTP POST` request using `REST API` in `Springboot`.

`HTTP GET` have been already implemented and they work fine, I'm following [this link](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/) but I got stuck on `POST` method.

I think `RestController` is right, but I have some doubts about the request that I'm sending to `Springboot` using terminal.

First of all, this is the model that I want to save on db (`Postgres`) using `POST` method, it's called `NFT` :

```
@Entity
public class NFT {
    
    public NFT(Long new_user_id) {
        this.title=getRandomString();
        this.price=0;
        this.description="Niente";
        this.image="";
        this.user_id=new_user_id;
    }
    
    public NFT() {
        this.title=getRandomString();
        this.price=0;
        this.description="Niente";
        this.image="";
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private Long user_id;
    
    public String title;
    
    public String image;
    
    public float price;

    public String description;
    
}
```

This class has 2 constructors, one using `User_ID` and the other is just an empty default constructor so I can make empty `post` request because `ID` will be autogenerated.

This is my rest class :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/restNFT")
public class NFTRestController {
        
    @Autowired
    private NFTService service;
    
    //curl GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/restNFT/1   example
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/{nft_id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Optional<NFT> getNFTbyID(@PathVariable int nft_id) {
        return service.getSingleNFTbyId((long) nft_id);
    }
    
    //curl GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/restNFT/user/1
    @RequestMapping(value="/user/{persona_id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<NFT> getAllNFTsFromPerson(@PathVariable int persona_id) {
        return service.getAllNFTsFromPerson((long) persona_id);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/nft",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveNFT(@RequestBody  NFT nft) {
        System.out.println(nft);
        service.saveNewNFT(nft);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/manyNFTs",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveAllNFTs(List<NFT> nfts) {
        service.saveAllNFT(nfts);
        return ;
    }
    
}
```

N.B. : `service.saveNewNFT(nft)` just calls `save()` method of `CrudRepository` interface.

`GET` requests work so I think that at least the first half of this class is correct, for example writing on terminal :

```
curl GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/restNFT/1
```

Returns correctly :

```
{"title":"yonwqelnrx","image":"","price":0.0,"description":"Nothing"}
```

But If I try to make an empty `POST` request :

```
curl POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/restNFT/nft -d '{}'
```

I expect a json as response from db, instead nothing is printed on screen.

EDIT :
Edited two functions :

```
@Transactional
    public NFT saveNewNFT(@RequestBody NFT nft) {   
        return nr.save(nft);
    }
```

And :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/nft",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public NFT saveNFT(@RequestBody  NFT nft) {
        return service.saveNewNFT(nft) ;
    }
```

Still testing with : `curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/restNFT/nft -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{}'` the result is the same, nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

The method you've mapped to that call, `saveNFT`, has a return type of void. Therefore, nothing (void) is returned in the response body.

Once you return the saved NFT, that will become the response body.

1. Update `NFTService#saveNewNFT(NFT)` to return the result of `CrudRepository#save(NFT)` -- this will return the persisted instance of the NFT (you might already be doing this)
2. Update `NFTRestController#saveNFT(NFT)` to return the result of `service.saveNewNFT(nft)` -- this will make the saved NFT the response body of your endpoint

Comment: Edited original post with new code but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem was inside security configuration class, I forgot to provide permissions for both `GET` and `POST` operations on `"/restNFT/**"` path :

```
public class AuthConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...//some code
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/","/restNFT/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/restNFT/**").permitAll()
```

Comment: As a note, you can add ` -v` or `--verbose` option to cURL to get it to print the HTTP response code, which can be especially helpful when you aren't seeing a response body. In this case, it likely would have been 401 or 403, which would have told you the issue is security related and not just because of the method returning void.